# Rate-limitting aiohttp.ClientSession() to make N requests per second

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to create an asynchronous SDK using `aiohttp` client for our service. I haven't been able to figure out how to throttle the `ClientSession()` to make only N requests per second.

```
class AsyncHTTPClient:
    def __init__(self, api_token, per_second_limit=10):
        self._client = aiohttp.ClienSession(
            headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer f{api_token}"}
        )
        self._throttler = asyncio.Semaphore(per_second_limit)
    
   async def _make_request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
       async with self._throttler:
           return await self._client.request(method, url, **kwargs)
   
   async def get(self, url, **params):
       return await self._make_request("GET", url, **params)

   async def close(self):
       await self._client.close()
```

I have this class with `get, post, patch, put, delete` methods implemented as a call to `_make_request`.

```
#As a user of the SDK I run the following code. 
async def main():
   try:
       urls = [some_url * 100]
       client = AsyncHTTPClient(my_token, per_second_limit=20)
       await asyncio.gather(*[client.get(url) for url in urls])
   finally:
       await client.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

`asyncio.Semaphore` limits the concurrency. That is, when the `main()` function is called, the `async with self._throttler` used in `client._make_request` limits concurrency to 20 requests. However, if the 20 requests finished within 1 second, then requests will be continuously made. What I want to do is make sure that only N requests (i.e. 20) are made in a second. If all 20 requests finished in 0.8 seconds, then sleep for 0.2 seconds and then process the requests again.

I looked up some `asyncio.Queue` examples with `workers` example but I am not sure how I will I implement it in my SDK since creating `workers` will have to be done by the user using this SDK and I want to avoid that, I want `AsyncHTTPClient` to handle the requests per second limit.

Any suggestions/advise/samples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `asyncio.sleep` to hard-limit the number of requests; see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61817461/4309792) if of any help.

Comment: Hello, any feedback please?